# foreach warning in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

admin TABLE

```
+--------------+---------------+
| Username     | Password      |
+--------------+---------------+
| JOHN         | 123           |
| EDWARD       | 123           |
+--------------+---------------+
```

my code

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
   echo" <table >";
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);      
 echo "<tr>";
     foreach($row as $key => $val){   
       echo"<th>$key</th> ";
  echo "</tr>";
    ///////////////////////////////
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

      echo"<tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){   
     foreach($row as $key => $val){   
       echo "<td>$val</td>";

     }
     echo "</tr>";

     }


    echo "</table>";
}
```

So, the problem is if there is more than 1 row in the result it outputs exactly what i want for e.g if i say:

```
SELECT Username from admin;


      +--------------+
      | Username     |
      +--------------+
      | JOHN         |
      | EDWARD       |
      +--------------+
```

But if there is only one row it does not show the COLUMN name and gives this warning

```
Select Username from admin where Username = 'JOHN';

    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  on line 65
      +--------------+
      | JOHN         |
      +--------------+
```

Comment: I'm not even sure why you're using foreach(). Just iterating through your results should be all you have to do.

Comment: could you add a `print_r($row)` call and share the output with us?

Comment: Using this `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);` twice is redundant.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if i remove the second one $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); i dont even get any output for the query "Select Username from admin where Username = 'JOHN';" i only get this "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Comment: @Mureinik i have tried it , it does not give the warning but it also doesnt output the column name

Comment: `Select Username from admin where Username = 'JOHN'` <= When would you _ever_ need to make that query? You obviously already have the username?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The table i provided you is for your understanding, the real tables are very complex

Answer (score 0):

Sneaky typo/logical coding error: you have a curly-bracket (brace) that's screwing everything up. Look at the end of the foreach used to generate the headings:

```
 foreach($row as $key => $val){   
   echo"<th>$key</th> ";
```

This should be:

```
  foreach($row as $key => $val)  
   echo"<th>$key</th> ";
```

And then remove the spurious brace at the very end.

This works (so long as there is at least 1 row to get the heaedrs):

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

echo " <table >";

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);      

echo "<tr>";
foreach($row as $key => $val)
    echo"<th>$key</th> ";

echo "</tr>";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

echo"<tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    foreach($row as $key => $val)
    {   
        echo "<td>$val</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, but its not the case!